# Linux mint Sudoers edit not working: can't do anything

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, sudo, sudoers

I am running Linux Mint. I set up an administrator account called 'thomas'.

I am trying to edit some files and it will only let me open them as read only. I assumed a permissions problem. As such, I sought to give myself the correct permissions.

I added my user to the group `sudo` (it was already in the group `admin`). In sudoers these groups have all permissions. However, this did not work so I added an entry specifically for my username to give it all permissions. Again, this has not worked.

As such, at the moment I can log in as root or put `sudo` in front of every command to get things working, but this is not ideal and does not help when, for example, I open up a document for editing in Gedit within the GUI.

Could anyone advise as to why my permission changes are not working?

Comment: Where are the files you are trying to edit? in your home directory? Can you give us the output of `ls -Al` in the directory of the files you're trying to edit?

Answer (score 1):

This is from my Red Hat-based desktop knowledge:

In a terminal do `su` and then `visudo` and then scroll down and look for:

```
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

Press <kbd>i</kbd> so you're in insert mode. Copy/paste the above line and replace root with your username, leave the rest as it is.

Comment: I have done this, and it hasn't worked - this is my question :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you can not edit files in `/home/thomas` without `sudo`? In that case change the ownership/permission of the files with `chown` and `chmod` respectively.

Editing files elsewhere on the file system will normally require administrative privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Try backing up your `/etc/sudoers` file (`su -c 'mv /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.bkup'`) then uninstalling and reinstalling sudo (`su -c 'apt-get remove sudo && apt-get install sudo'`)

When su -c asks for a password, it is asking for root password.

While I don't recommend doing this, it may be possible if you change the uid for `thomas` to 0. This should be possible with `sudo vim /etc/passwd` (use whatever file editor you use).

Comment: I did this. It reinstalled. The sudoers file stayed the same, and the problem persists.

Comment: Can you edit the output of ls -Al in the directory of the files you're trying to edit into the question?

Answer (score 1):

### Fix permissions within user thomas: (as Thor suggested)

```
find /home/thomas -type f -exec sudo chown thomas:thomas {} \;
find /home/thomas -type d -exec sudo chown thomas:thomas {} \;

find /home/thomas -type f -exec sudo chmod 640 {} \;
find /home/thomas -type d -exec sudo chmod 750 {} \;
```

### Important:

Files not located in `/home/thomas` will not have permissions for you to edit without sudo.

This is normal! It's critical for maintaining a safe running system.

Comment: To clarify.. When logged in as user 'thomas' I can edit files in my Home directory.

I cannot however edit files in the htdocs section of my xampp install located at /opt/lampp/htdocs

I could change the ownership of these files (which i believe is what your code accomplishes), but I was trying to find a find all remedy - I want my account 'thomas' to be able to do everything.

Could you clarify on your 'Important' - why?/What has adding thomas to the group sudo and giving all permissions to thomas actually achieved?

Thanks

Comment: user account thomas shouldn't be able to do everything. *nix works with the principle of least privilege. thomas shouldn't be able to do everything, root should. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege

Comment: thanks Rob for providing him with the link, kid wouldn't let me get here. lol .. Now i advise against this but he could change the permissions on  /opt/lampp/"""htdocs""" lampp:lampp or what ever the owner is and set file perms as 664 then simply add himself to that group. Sorry for the long winded comment lol.

Comment: Ok - thanks for the info.. so.. I wanted to install xampp to use for testing my websites. I could not do it from the user account 'thomas' as it didnt have the required priveleges.. so i logged into root and installed it.

tao - you seem to be suggesting that giving 'thomas' priveleges to edit files in opt/lampp is inadvisable? why? If so is the assumption that i should just use root for my webdesign?